# sforce.one.navigateToRelatedList Is not working

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am new in salesforce and I'm trying to make a call from a visualforce page inside salesforce1 (now called lightning, I think) to a Related List of contacts. My page show some options related to the Account object and one of this options is to show its Contacts (that's what I want but this code is not working):

```
<apex:outputPanel > 
        <a href="sforce.one.navigateToRelatedList('Contacts', '{!idAccount}');"> 
        <input type="button" value="Contacts" class="register-button"/>
    </a>        
</apex:outputPanel>
```

I just want to show this: Is the same that you can see in Salesforce Lightning under Accounts/Related/Contacts

[image: Account salesforce]

and then

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="sforce.one.navigateToRelatedList('Contacts', '{!idAccount}');">
```

This code isn't executing the JavaScript but instead trying to navigate to an invalid URL.

try href="javascript:sforce.one.navigateToRelatedList('Contacts', '{!idAccount}')"

Comment: Oh Thanks a lot. I didn't know that. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: Glad to help. :)